# ¿Cómo leer más de un fichero .txt a la vez en Java?

Tags: java

quiero leer 3 archivos txt pero no se como separar el código por clases y objetos. No sé como llamarlos en el main pasando como parámetro el objeto y la estructura.

Lo q hago es leer el txt, pasarlo al mapa para ordenarlo y mostrarlo en pantalla.

```
public void ordena(){

        hashMap<Integer, estructura> ordenar = new hashMap<Integer, estructura>();

        FileReader Entrada = null; 
        try { 
            Entrada = new FileReader("archivo.txt"); 
            BufferedReader linea = new BufferedReader(Entrada); 
            String cadena;

            while((cadena = linea.readLine())!= null) {
                 String[] separador = cadena.split(" "); 

                  // Añade los elemento al Map
               ordenar.put(Integer.parseInt(separador[1]), new estructura(separador[0],Integer.parseInt(separador[1])));           
        }

             for (estructura po : ordenar.values()) {
            System.out.println(po.toString()+ " ");
                }
        linea.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("error no se encuentra el archivo"+ ex);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no leer uno luego otro y así sucesivamente? Si de pronto hay 4 ficheros para leer en lugar de 3 ¿volverías a escribir el programa?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Podes abrir 3 threads diferentes, uno para cada archivo. O podés usar un ExecutorService para hacer algo similar pero sin tener que crear y administar los Threads.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque tu duda no es concreta, no está mal tu lógica, y debes de recordar que las transmisiones abiertas debes de cerrarlas, espero te sirva de ayuda el siguiente código:

```
            FileReader f = new FileReader("archivo.txt");
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
            while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(cadena);
            }
            b.close();
```

Para lo que tu quieres hacer de leer los tres archivos, puedes guardarlos en un array del tipo `FileReader` y recorrelos con un ciclo `for`. y dentro del ciclo `for` agregas el ciclo `while` espero te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

```
FileReader archivos[] = {new FileReader("archivo1.txt"), new FileReader("archivo2.txt"),new FileReader("archivo3.txt")};
```

Comment: BufferedReader linea = new BufferedReader(archivos[]); y se  puedemeter en este

Comment: @Luiis claro lo que hace es que obtienes el valor de archivos[i] y lo guardas en linea.

Comment: @WTFChamp igual puede convertir su try en un try con recursos :)